# Why child element does not move relative to its parent?

Tags: html, css

I want the child element to go down relative to its parent element, but the child element goes down relative to the whole html file.

```
.parent{
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  position:absolute; top:5px;
}


HTML Code:

<h1 class="parent">Hello World</h1>

<h2 class="child">Bye World</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `h1` and `h2` are called siblings not parent and child. You can learn more at [here](https://sebastian.expert/ancestor-descendant-sibling-parent-child-explained/).

And shouldn't use `h1` as parent of `h2`.
You can use a `div` as parent.

Example

```css
.parent{
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
}
.txt-xl {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.txt-l {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span class="txt-xl">Hello World</span>
  <span class="child txt-l">Bye World</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The child element should be inside the parent element to respect that.

Example:

```
<h1 class="parent">
 Hello World
 <h2 class="child">Bye World</h2>
</h1>
```

Comment: I tried that, but no changes. Is the CSS code correct?

Comment: @Parham Try using <div> instead <h1 / h2>. Also modify the .child css as Vick Sain says if you don't want to overlap the two texts.

Answer (score 2):

Child should be inside the parent element. so that it can be relative to parent element.

```
<h1 class="parent">
 Hello World
 <h2 class="child">Bye World</h2>
</h1>
```

CSS

```
.child{
  position:absolute; top:auto; bottom: 5px
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp

Comment: I tried that, but no changes. Is the CSS code correct?

Comment: instead to top use it 

.child{
  position:absolute; top:auto; bottom: -5px;
}